# How do I make a png show up on a material?

Tags: transparency, emission

I thought this would be simple. It really should be, but for some reason when I add an image texture to the material it barely shows up. You can't even see the "You" and you can barely see the "Tube". I've done this a hundred times and this is the first time I've had this happen. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That fixed it! I've done this before, but it was for a gradient. I also had my emission set to white, not black. Thanks!

Comment: You could even plug in the image for emission color